# Cannot connect Github organization repository to AWS Amplify app

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

I am trying to create an AWS Amplify application that is connected to a Github organization repository.

When I am asked to select a Github repository to connect the app in AWS Amplify I do not see any of my organization's repositories.

How do I connect AWS Amplify to my organization's repositories so that they are listed in the repository drop down?

I have confirmed that I have admin access to both the Github organization and repository in question.

It seems to me that I need to add an AWS service to the organization's Third Party Access settings in Github but I am not sure which one and how.

Answer (score 45):

Go to your Github account and remove the App Authorisation:

```
https://github.com/settings/applications
```

Then on Amplify, reconnect to Github, it will ask you an Authorisation and here you can choose your organisation at the bottom of the prompt box.

Comment: Now there is no need to delete the connection. After accessing the URL mentioned above, click on the connection name, it will display Permissions and Organization access. Under organization access you will see the list of organizations that you have access to; click on [Grant] or [Reques] button to grant Amplify access to the Organization repositorires.